# XCOPY batch file

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

I’m looking to create a batch file that transfers all my music from my external drive to my Samsung note 3. The idea is just to click the batch file and for it to update any song on my external on my phone.

Heres what I’ve got

```
XCOPY "E:\Music\*.*" "Computer\SAMSUNG-SM-N900A\Phone\Music\" /e /c /r /k /y /v
```

The problem I see is that it’s creating a folder on my desktop with that path, the directory on my desktop being computer with the following subfolders.

I’m not sure why it won’t recognize the path, any ideas?

Comment: It is MTP, not ordinary file system. It does not support standard filesystem operations, so you can't directly access it from cmd or other programs (possible from windows explorer because it have plugin for that). Take a look at http://superuser.com/questions/369959/how-do-i-access-mtp-devices-on-the-command-line-in-windows

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly copy files from windows to an android device, its a different file system. You can probably do it manually with this program:
https://android-file-manager.en.softonic.com/